# Create application using sencha cmd but deploy it without "building" it

Tags: extjs, cmd

I got the following situation:
I've started to build a extjs 5 application using sencha cmd line tool (which I like really much).

The problem: 
The customer wants to maintain the application by himself after delivery, but he's not willing to learn (and to set up a workspace for) the sencha cmd line tool.

The question:
How could I handle this? I would like to develop the application using sencha cmd, and deploy it without "building" it (means: not to use "sencha app build" command).

Of course I could put the project together "by hand", but that's not really a smart way, I guess...
Any suggestion? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you need to build.
If you have scss theme settings you need sencha cmd.
If you need to make custom theme changes you can make a theme project and run sencha cmd for the customer as needed.

I've developed many ext apps without using sencha cmd.
Using eclipse you can create a dynamic web project.
Put the ext into a directory (extjs) and include all the js and packages from the extjs5 sdk build folder.
From there have everything needed (controller,store,model,view) in the app folder structure.
Use an ant build or better gradle and package the product in a war from the WebContent folder.
Then use SVN or the like to do your code repository for backup.

```
WebContent  
-->app  
---->controller  
---->model  
---->store  
---->view  
-->extjs  
---->packages  
---->ext.js (all other needed js like bootstrap.js etc)  
-->resources 
---->app.js  
---->css  
---->images   
-->WEB-INF
```

How much will the customer "maintain" the app.
I mean will you develop new features or will the customer?
If you will do the new features then it might be better to do all the sencha cmd yourself and deliver the app to the customer and they do minor fixes.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll think about that. Regarding to your question: The customer will do only minor changes, new features will be added by us (hopefully ;))